# Python imshow: Completely filled and completely blank image, no differences at all

Tags: python, image-processing, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have two 28x28 matrices, one filled with 0.5s and other filled with -0.5s

```
show_difference(matrix_filled, matrix_empty)
```

Results in:

[image]

Also, to make sure I'm not messing with the values shader can accept, I also tried,

```
show_difference(matrix_filled*0, matrix_filled*2)
# numpy arrays
```

**However I still get the same results! Why?**

---

Here's the function I use to show them side by side:

```
def show_difference(image_a, image_b):
    plt.subplot(1,2,1)
    plt.imshow(image_a, interpolation='none')

    plt.subplot(1,2,2)
    plt.imshow(image_b, interpolation='none')

    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `imshow` plot is normalized individually on its minimum and maximum value. Since minimum and maximum are the same for a constant array, all pixels will have the lowest color from the colormap. And thus both plots look the same.

To define a normalization you may use the `vmin` `vmax`  arguments of `imshow`, e.g.

```
plt.imshow(array, vmin=0, vmax=2)
```

or use a normalization instance, e.g.

```
norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=2)
plt.imshow(array, norm=norm)
```

So in your case you may first find out the minimum and maximum of both arrays and use those values for the image plot

```
def show_difference(image_a, image_b):
    norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=np.min([image_a.min(),image_b.min()]),
                         vmax=np.max([image_a.max(),image_b.max()])  )

    plt.subplot(1,2,1)
    plt.imshow(image_a, interpolation='none', norm=norm)

    plt.subplot(1,2,2)
    plt.imshow(image_b, interpolation='none', norm=norm)

    plt.show()
```